# Netty - Does closing the socket at the client end close the channel at the server

Tags: java, sockets, netty

My TCP server is implemented using Netty. My client using vanilla java.net.Socket to connect to this server. I'm using the same socket to send multiple requests to the server. Once done with all the requests the client calls `socket.close()`.

I'm not closing the channel anywhere in my server code. Also, I've set TCP KEEP_ALIVE on my server. Will closing the socket on the client end automatically close the channel on the server or do I've to do something else explicitly and what is the best practice ?

Comment: You might want to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165670/socket-close-in-java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if an application closes a socket, its remote peer also notices that the closure.  Therefore, you don't need to call close() on both side.  However, sometimes, due to network problems, you might not get notified when the remote peer closes the connection.  To work around this problem, it's a good idea to send some message periodically, and then you will detect the unexpected closure sooner.

Please note SO_KEEP_ALIVE will not help much here because for most operating systems because the default keep alive time is very long.